# Prove or disprove: $f$ is bounded on $[0,\infty )$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Prove or disprove: let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a continuous function, if $f$ is strictly positive and $ \int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, then $f$ is bounded on $[0,\infty )$.
I tried to disprove it by a function like $x\mapsto \frac x{1+x\sin^2x} $ which is not bounded and it's minimum value converges to zero in order to make the integral converge, but it's not. Any help!

Comment: Take $f$ to be zero everywhere except for thin and tall triangular bumps with areas $2^{-n}$. You can place isosceles triangles with bases centered at the integers $n=1,2,3,...$, with heights $2^{n}$ and base $2^{-2n+1}$.

Comment: I suspect a counterexample may be easier than a proof

Comment: but $f$ is strictly positive!

Comment: but then the function woudn't be continuous

Comment: Take @plop 's counterexample and add a strictly positive function that is integrable, such as $e^{-x}$.

Comment: And plop's function is continuous.